# Writing string representation of class instance to file

Tags: python, class, file-io

I have defined the `__str__` and `__repr__` in my `class foo`
When I `print foo()`, it works just fine.
Of course, redefining stdout as a `file` object and calling `print foo()` would write the string representation to the file, but is that the most pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("Output.txt", "w") as outputFile:
    print >>outputFile, foo()
```

Python docs recommend using `with`, in this section http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is
>   also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

Comment: Is this recommended over what @jbarber has suggested?. Asking purely out of curiosity

Comment: I believe so. I never worry about closing the file after reading or writing when I use `with`.

Answer (score 5):

Simply call [`str`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#func-repr) or [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#func-repr) on the object, like this:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(repr(foo()))
```

Comment: Why do I need `io` here?

Comment: You didn't say whether your program runs on Python 2 or Python 3, and `io.open` happens to work on both.

Comment: so `open('somefile','w') as f: f.write()` wouldn't work. But `io.open` would?. That's interesting.

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge Sorry, actually `open` is the better choice here. `io.open` is the clean version to work with texts (and you can explicitly pick an encoding). But the `repr` in Python 2.x doesn't return a character, but a bytestring, so one needs the old plain `open` here. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.7, you can temporarily direct your print to stdout in this fashion:

```
>>> print >> open('test.txt', 'w'), 'test string'
```

If you are using Python 3.3, you can temporarily direct your print to stdout in this fashion:

```
>>> print('test string', file=open('test.txt', 'w'))
```

Both of these methods allow you to switch the output temporarily.

As deque starmap partial setattr has pointed out below, in Python 2.7, you can also temporarily direct your print to stdout in this fashion:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('test string', file=open('test.txt', 'w'))
```

Comment: the second form is also available in python 2 with the `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Accepting @thefourtheye 's answer because of him mentioning the guarantee of file handling closing when `with` is used. How would you go about testing if the handle is still open after the print finishes? There isn't a way to reference the object without giving it a name, Right? Maybe `id` can be used somehow

Comment: @Lelouch Lamperouge Using the with keyword is often a good idea. At the same time, file objects are automatically garbage collected the last time they are referenced in a program, so you don't always need to close open file objects. Still, it's good practice to close them. The above was abbreviated merely to demonstrate in a concise form how this works. By all means, use a context manager in your code.